# Overwrite/force push an existing package version in gemfury

Tags: build, release-management, gem-fury

We are using gemfury to manage our internal python package releases. The issue I am facing right now is that gemfury doesn't allow pushing/overwriting the same version, which is good in a way when dealing with production builds. This is difficult to manage in case of dev/qa builds. We do increment version and release when releasing production versions.

Is there a flag that can be used to force push/overwrite a package version? Eg. If someone pushes some change to my QA branch, I build the branch and release the new build, but I want to call it version 'qa' always. So this way, I always want the 'qa' version to point to the latest version of my QA build. I have a jenkins job to do this.

I really need an api/flag to overwrite an existing version to accomplish what I am trying to achieve with respect to automating our development and release process. Please let me know if something like this is available.

Comment: Which language & package manager are you using?

Comment: Python and pip @Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete the latest package version using below CLI and continue with new upload ([source](https://gemfury.com/help/gemfury-cli/#removing-packages))

```
fury yank package-name -v 0.1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

It might not help your cause, but from Gemfury website I select the version I want to upgrade, delete it and then upload the new package with same version.

I think that way you can automate as well.

Comment: I need to automate this via jenkins. For now I have made a workaround to add jenkins build number to the version. This keeps my package always updated at gemfury. As far as doing it via the website is concerned, I am aware of that. Just that in order to automate, I would have to reverse engineer the ajax request being sent upon deleting the package from their web UI.